# WordNet - What does n and the number represent?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, part-of-speech

My question is related to [WordNet Interface](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html).

```
   >>> wn.synsets('cat')
       [Synset('cat.n.01'), Synset('guy.n.01'), Synset('cat.n.03'),
        Synset('kat.n.01'), Synset('cat-o'-nine-tails.n.01'), 
        Synset('caterpillar.n.02'), Synset('big_cat.n.01'), 
        Synset('computerized_tomography.n.01'), Synset('cat.v.01'), 
        Synset('vomit.v.01')]
    >>>
```

I could not find the answer to what is the purpose of `n` and the following `number` in `cat.n.01` or `caterpillar.n.02`.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what “wordnet” means for Python. If “wordnet” is a library, make that term a link to the home page so we can know what you're referring to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the [NLTK docs](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html?highlight=wordnet#nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Lemma.synset), a `<lemma>.<pos>.<number>` Synset string is composed of the following parts:

> - `<lemma>` is the word’s morphological stem
> - `<pos>` is one of the module attributes ADJ, ADJ_SAT, ADV, NOUN or VERB
> - `<number>` is the sense number, counting from 0

Thus, the `<pos>` is the part of speech. 
According to [the wordnet man page](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/wndb.5WN.html), the part of speech character has the following meaning:

```
n    NOUN
v    VERB
a    ADJECTIVE
s    ADJECTIVE SATELLITE
r    ADVERB
```

The `<number>` is used to disambiguate word meanings.