# Python NTLK: words change part of speech tag when converted to synsets

Tags: python, wordnet

I am trying to measure word similarity in Python, using the NTLK library for wordnet. However, sometimes words I'm trying to convert to synsets change their part of speech tag, for example:

Input:

```
x = wn.synset('terrible.a.01') 
x
```

Output:

```
Synset('awful.s.02')
```

Which makes "x" unable to be compared to other adjectives since its tag is now "s" instead of "a". I never worked with WordNet before, can someone explain why this happens, and what "s" and "02" mean?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34831167/841830  (s means "adjective satellite"; you could safely treat them the same as "a", I imagine).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordNet - What does n and the number represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831167/wordnet-what-does-n-and-the-number-represent)